# Assign NA in conditional for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function that assigns NA to all columns that return TRUE on the condition `((sum of column values)/total number of rows) < 0.1`

I tried something like this:

```
matrix <- cbind(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
            c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1), 
            c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0),
            c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

filter10 <- function(a) {
              for (i in seq(ncol(a))) {
                if ((sum(a[,i])/nrow(a)) < 0.1) 
                  a[,i] = NA
              }
}
```

but nothing happens to the matrix after

```
> filter10(matrix)
>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `return` in your function, otherwise it returns nothing.

```
filter10 <- function(a) {
  for (i in seq(ncol(a))) {
    if ((sum(a[,i])/nrow(a)) < 0.1) 
      a[,i] = NA
  }
  return(a)
}

filter10(m)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    0    1    1   NA
#  [2,]    1    1    0   NA
#  [3,]    1    1    0   NA
#  [4,]    1    1    0   NA
#  [5,]    0    0    0   NA
#  [6,]    1    1    1   NA
#  [7,]    0    0    0   NA
#  [8,]    1    0    1   NA
#  [9,]    0    1    1   NA
# [10,]    1    0    1   NA
# [11,]    0    0    1   NA
# [12,]    1    1    0   NA
```

By the way, you can also have it way easier avoiding the `for` loop:

```
filter10.1 <- function(a) {a[, colSums(a) / nrow(a) < .1] <- NA;a}
filter10.1(m)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    0    1    1   NA
#  [2,]    1    1    0   NA
#  [3,]    1    1    0   NA
#  [4,]    1    1    0   NA
#  [5,]    0    0    0   NA
#  [6,]    1    1    1   NA
#  [7,]    0    0    0   NA
#  [8,]    1    0    1   NA
#  [9,]    0    1    1   NA
# [10,]    1    0    1   NA
# [11,]    0    0    1   NA
# [12,]    1    1    0   NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the second approach though, although more elegant: what's the a in```NA;a``` supposed to do?

Comment: @vankappa The `;` is equivalent to a line break and makes it possible to make a neat one-liner.